# Get dataset cover image from kaggle using python selenium web scraping

Tags: python, selenium, kaggle

**Hi, Please how can i scrap the cover image of datasets from kaggle using python selenium ?
or just get the value of "src" of the HTML**

*View img =*> [image of inspect elem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lmjA.png)

Answer (score 0):

This code uses selenium to get the source of the cover image element and then download it using requests:

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

driver= webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(kaggle_website)

cover_src = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath/to/image').get_attribute("src")
response = requests.get(cover_src)
```